# How should jsdom be configured with NuxtJS?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

I'm trying to use jQuery on NuxtJS. After following [this tutorial](https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-use-jquery-in-nuxtjs), I obviously get errors saying that jQuery needs a window context. I installed jsdom and all of its dependencies and use it [as it should be](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), but every time I run `npm run dev` the following error always pops up:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                      friendly-errors 14:13:40

These dependencies were not found:                                                           friendly-errors 14:13:40
                                                                                             friendly-errors 14:13:40
* child_process in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js                   friendly-errors 14:13:40
* fs in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/resource-loader.js, ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js and 2 others
                                                                                             friendly-errors 14:13:40
To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs
```

Note those dependencies are indeed installed and up-to-date. Is this due to a conflict of sides on Nuxt? How would it be solved entirely or otherwise?

I've also set up a plugin to always have the default window context through jsdom:

**jsdom.js**

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom")
const { JSDOM } = jsdom

const { document } = new JSDOM("").window
global.document = document
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use jsdom, you have to modify nuxt.configure.js. After modifying nuxt.configure.js, restart nuxt.

```
export default {
  // some configurations
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isClient) {
        config.node = {
          fs: 'empty',
          child_process: 'empty',
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // other configurations
}
```

If you encountered with same dependency error, just add the same settings in config.node like below.

```
          fs: 'empty',
          child_process: 'empty',
          tls: 'empty',
          net: 'empty',
```

In this case, I suppose that you don't really need to use fs, child_process in your code, but they prevent you importing jsdom. 
With configuration mentioned above, you can replace fs and child_proccess with empty object, and suppress build error. So if you try to use function which depends on these libraries, like fetch with file scheme, it will be failed.

Details about config.node are documented here : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#other-node-core-libraries